# How to debug "Uncaught (in promise)" in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In the developers tools I set both "Pause on uncaught exceptions" and even "Pause on caught exceptions", but still when an error happens in a promise, it simply gets dumped to the Console. Debugger does not break there.

Comment: Add some console.log statements to see what the state is before this happens?  Once you know the trigger, set breakpoints before that?

Comment: Try `window.onunhandledrejection=console.warn` before running the code to print the call stack.